# WinUI DataGrid (from CommunityToolkit): How to get the currently selected cell?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-community-toolkit, winui-3

in a WinUI 3 application, I am using the `DataGrid` from the `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls` namespace, see [MSDN DataGrid class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagrid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0).

I am looking for a way the get the instance of the currently selected or clicked `DataGridCell`.

I need this because I would like to show a `MenuFlyout` when the user selects / clicks a certain cell (The `MenuFlyout` control is like a little popup window, see [MSDN MenuFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout?view=winui-3.0)). This flyout should than be displayed next to cell. For this, the `MenuFlyout` class has a `ShowAt` method available which accepts a parameter of type `FrameworkElement` ("The element to use as the flyout's placement target."). I want to pass the currently selected cell to this method.

This is my current code:

```
    private void MyDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();
        MenuFlyoutItem item = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item.Text = "Test";
        flyout.Items.Add(item);

        // How do I get an instance of the currently selected cell in the DataGrid?
        FrameworkElement theCurrentlySelectedCell = ?;
        flyout.ShowAt(theCurrentlySelectedCell);
    }
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get an instance of the currently selected / clicked cell of the DataGrid. I could not find anything in the `DataGrid` class which I found helpful for that.
Unfortunatly the `CurrentCellChanged` event which I use in the code example above does not have this information in its event arguments either, it just has a parameter `e` of type `EventArgs`. The `sender` in that case is the DataGrid, not the cell.

What I did find is that there is a CurrentColumn property on the DataGrid, see [MSDN DataGrid CurrentColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagrid.currentcolumn?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0). But I was not able to get from this instance to the `DataGridCell` instances of the row.

Does anyone know how to get an instance of the currently selected or clicked `DataGridCell`?

Comment: Have you checked the SelectionChanged event? Maybe it suits your needs better, as it provides a SelectionChangedEventArgs.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me. The SelectionChangedEventArgs contains an 'AddedItems' property, but this just contains instances of the data objects that are bound to each row, or more precisely to the row(s) that are now selected. The 'OriginalSource' property is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution to my problem, but it does not involve getting the instance of the selected `DataGridCell`.

What I do in order to work with the element of a cell is changing the respective column of the `DataGrid` to a column of type `DataGridTemplateColumn`.
This allows defining the controls which make up each cell. For instance using a `Button` or `DropDownButton` as cell content.

The following code declaratively creates a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which renders the content of the property `Text` of class `ViewModelForRowData` using a `DropDownButton`.
The `DropDownButton` displays `MenuFlyout` next to the button (see my question). The dropdwon has three options (menu items) that will appear if the user clicks on the `DropDownButton` that represents the cell content. Because the `DropDownButton` actually is the cell content, this is effectively that what I need, i.e. I do not need the clicked `DataGridCell` instance itself:

```
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:ViewModelForRowData">
                        <DropDownButton Content="{x:Bind Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <DropDownButton.Flyout>
                                <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom" ShowMode="Transient">
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu Option 1" Command="{x:Bind Command1}" />
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu Option 2" Command="{x:Bind Command2}" />   
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu Option 3" Command="{x:Bind Command3}" />   
                                </MenuFlyout>
                            </DropDownButton.Flyout>
                        </DropDownButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

An alternative would be creating the `MenuFlyout` in a code behind file, that gets called as a result of a button click event handler.

```
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" >
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:ViewModelForRowData">
                        <Button Content="{x:Bind Text}" Click="ButtonClick"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>



    private void ButtonClick(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;

        if (button == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();

        MenuFlyoutItem item1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item1.Text = "TestItem 1";
        flyout.Items.Add(item1);

        MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item2.Text = "TestItem 2";
        flyout.Items.Add(item2);

        FlyoutShowOptions flyoutShowOptions = new FlyoutShowOptions();
        flyout.ShowAt(button, flyoutShowOptions);
    }
```

In that case the `sender` parameter of the event handler references the button, so i can use this to specify the first parameter of the `MenuFlyout.ShowAt` method.